# Create User with AngularFire and call factory to display notifications

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire, angular-promise

I'm new to AngularJS and trying to use it in combination with AngularFire/Firebase to store some project data. I build a factory which should handle notifications to display them on a central location. The factory looks like this:

```
myApp.factory("AlertService", function($timeout){
  var alerts = new Array();

  var addAlert = function(type, message){
    alerts.push({
      type: type,
      msg: message
    });
    $timeout(function(){
      removeAlert(alerts.length - 1);
    }, 3000);
  }

  var removeAlert = function(index){
    alerts.splice(index, 1);
  }

  return{
    alerts : alerts,
    addSuccessAlert : function(message){
      addAlert("success", message);
    },
    addDangerAlert : function(message){
      addAlert("danger", message);
    },
    deleteAlert : function(index){
      removeAlert(index);
    }
  };
});
```

Binding the data in the controller I used $watch

```
$scope.$watch( function () { return AlertService.alerts; }, function ( alerts ) {
  $scope.alerts = AlertService.alerts;
});
```

and just placed a div in the index.html:

```
<div id="alert">
  <alert ng-repeat="alert in alerts" type="{{alert.type}}">{{alert.msg}}</alert>
</div>
```

This is perfectly working if I call `AlertService.addWarningAlert("Your password is not identical");` from within a controller. But if I now try to display a notification after creating a user in firebase the databinding is not getting updated (only the array). Thats how I create the user:

```
var ref = new Firebase("https://xyz.firebaseio.com/"); 
ref.createUser({
  email    : $scope.data.suEmail,
  password : $scope.data.suPassword
}, function(error) {
  if (error === null) {
    console.log("User created successfully");
    AlertService.addSuccessAlert("User created successfully");
  } else {
    console.log("Error creating user:", error);
    AlertService.addWarningAlert("Error creating user");
  }
});
```

Any idea what I'm (stupidly) doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

Edit: Here the Plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/jSaJ5EzZ5MGRPFzhbGJg?p=preview

Comment: Can you reproduce this in a Plunkr or JSBIN?

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply. Here the Plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/jSaJ5EzZ5MGRPFzhbGJg?p=preview "Add Alert on Click" is working. If you select "Add Alert on Callback" the console.log() operation is working but the notification is not displayed. If you click on the "Add Alert on Callback" button multiple times some notification are getting displayed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are only using the Firebase JavaScript library and not [AngularFire](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/quickstart.html). AngularFire is built on top of the Firebase JS library and Angular. AngularFire does a lot of useful things such as, auto synchronizing [objects](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/quickstart.html#section-objects) and [arrays](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/quickstart.html#section-arrays) (you might want to check that out for your array example). AngularFire also handles `$scope.apply` properly. This way any updates are applied to the view.

If you choose not use AngularFire, you'll need to wrap the parts of your code that update the view in the `$timeout` service.

**[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/GZfQRXVS0D5FmzNPR658?p=preview)**

```
  $scope.createUser = function(){
    ref.createUser({
        email    : "a.b@c.com",
        password : "mypassword"
      }, function(error) {

        // this will update the view because it's wrapped in $timeout
        $timeout(function() {
          if (error === null) {
            console.log("User created successfully");
            AlertService.addSuccessAlert("User created successfully");
          } else {
            console.log("Error creating user:", error);
            AlertService.addWarningAlert("Error while creating user");
          }
        });

      });
  }
```

I highly recommend giving the AngularFire docs a good read. It will save you a fair amount of time in your project.

Comment: Works! Thank you! I was not using AngularFire at this point because I don't want to store the notifications in the DB. But as user handling is next I will most likely come back to your other links ;) Thanks again!

Comment: @andinho, your comment here doesn't make any sense. You are calling push() above but state that you don't want to store your data in the "DB" (Firebase isn't a database, it's a real-time persistence layer). AngularFire isn't about user handling. It's a real-time binding that synchronizes Firebase data with Angular's views and is perfectly suited for what you have above. Also, David's answer is spot on.